# SQL redact column B value when column A value is too unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

In the table below, I want to use SQL to replace a `UserID` when a `GroupID` has `<=1` unique `UserID`'s associated with it:

| GroupID | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 789 |
| 2 | 987 |
| 3 | 876 |
| 3 | 765 |

The returned result would look like this:

| GroupID | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 789 |
| 2 | redacted |
| 3 | 876 |
| 3 | 765 |

The use case here would be to prevent the ability to identify a single user based on a group. If a group has more than one user, that it considered anonymous enough to display.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use derived table and apply logic as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(GroupID    int, UserID int)

insert into @table values
(1,123),
(1,456),
(1,789),
(2,987),
(3,876),
(3,765);

select groupid,case when distinctgroupcount =1 then 'redact' else cast(userid as varchar(10)) end as userid
from
(
select *, count(*) over(partition by groupid) as distinctgroupcount 
from @table
) as t
```

| groupid | userid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 789 |
| 2 | redact |
| 3 | 876 |
| 3 | 765 |

Answer (score 3):

Just another option using the window function `sum() over()`

**Example**

```
Select GroupID
      ,UserID   = case when sum(1) over (partition by GroupID) = 1 then 'Redacted' else left(UserID,25) end
 from YourTable
```

**Results**

```
GroupID UserID
1       123
1       456
1       789
2       Redacted
3       876
3       765
```

Comment: Nice, since it allows for the "too unique" threshold to be adjusted to values other than 1. (Purely subjective, but count(*) also works in place of sum(1) and might be clearer.)

Comment: @TN True but I save 2 whole characters :)

Comment:  for saving 2chrs. +1 ne.way for a gd ansr.

Comment: This is awesome, and I love the ability to implement a variable threshold. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate functions partitioned over a *window*:

```
select GroupId, 
    case when Min(userid) over(partition by groupid) =  Max(userid) over(partition by groupid) 
      then 'redacted' 
        else Cast(userid as varchar(10)) 
    end as UserId
from t
```

Note this assumed *userId* is an integer data type, if it's already a *varchar* you don't need to cast it.

Comment: Appreciate your help ^^